# Get maximum value with grouping on multiple fields in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have data in MongoDB database like as below:

```
ClientCategory table:
 {
   _id:ObjectId(‘xxxxxxxx’),
   categoryName:’factory expense’
 },
 {
   _id:ObjectId(‘xxxxxxxx’),
   categoryName:’rent’
 }
 ..... and so on
 Transaction table:

 {
   _id:ObjectId(‘xxxxxxxx’),
   clientDefaultCategory:"factory expense",
   categoryId:ObjectId(‘xxxxxx’),
   amount:100,
   date:’01-05-2021’
 },
 {
   _id:ObjectId(‘xxxxxxxx’),
   clientDefaultCategory:"factory expense",
   categoryId:ObjectId(‘xxxxxx’),
   amount:50,
   date:’02-05-2021’
 },
 {
  _id:ObjectId(‘xxxxxxxx’),
  clientDefaultCategory:"rent",
  categoryId:ObjectId(‘xxxxxx’),
  amount:200,
  date:’05-05-2021’
 }
{
 _id:ObjectId(‘xxxxxxxx’),
 clientDefaultCategory:"factory expense",
 categoryId:ObjectId(‘xxxxxx’),
 amount:50,
 date:’01-04-2021’
},
{
 _id:ObjectId(‘xxxxxxxx’),
 clientDefaultCategory:"factory expense",
 categoryId:ObjectId(‘xxxxxx’),
 amount:250,
 date:’02-04-2021’
},
{
 _id:ObjectId(‘xxxxxxxx’),
 clientDefaultCategory:"rent",
 categoryId:ObjectId(‘xxxxxx’),
 amount:200,
 date:’05-04-2021’
}
```

I want to get the maximum value of a month among the categories means what is the maximum value if I group them with a category also I want to group them per month as well.

Here is my code:

```
const lookup = {
$lookup: {
  from: "clientcategories",
  localField: "CategoryId",
  foreignField: "_id",
  as: "categories",
 },
};

const unwind = {
  $unwind: "$categories",
};
const match = {
$match: {
  userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId),
  date: {
    $gte: startDate,
    $lte: endDate,
  },
 },
};
const group = {
 $group: {
  _id: {
    category: "$categories.ClientDefaultCategory",
    id: "$categories._id",
  },
  total: { $sum: "$amount" },
 },
};
```

I have tried multiple aggregations to get the data but not success, I want as like `maxValue:300`
explain: as in 5th month there are entries but a total of one category is less then 4th month category. if there is any case same value in any month or any category then max its fine, I need only maximum value of one month among the categories.

if not possible then if we got data like as below then it will also fine

```
   {
     _id:{category:categoryName,id:xxxxxx},
     amount:300
   }
   {
     _id:{category:categoryName,id:xxxxxx},
     amount:200
    }
```

If needs more explanation then let me, Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. as per your statement *as in 5th month there are entries but a total of one category is less then 4th month category* i can not see any month field in your expected result.